# counting using permutation and combination(Rosen)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A professor packs her collection of $40$ issues of a mathematics journal in four boxes with $10$ issues per box. How many ways can she distribute the journals if

a)  each box is numbered, so that they are distinguishable?

b) the boxes are identical, so that they cannot be distinguished?

---

I attempted:

part a) where I found this question to be of the form distributing indistinguishable object into distinguishable boxes governed by formula $C(n+r-1,r)$

so in my question $n=4$ and $r=10$,so is $C(4+10-1,10)$ is solution of part a) .correct me and part b) I have no idea

Comment: For part a) it is $\frac{40!}{(10!)^4}$ and for the second part, it is $\frac{40!}{4!\times (10!)^4}$, assuming that the issues are distinguishable.

Comment: please explain @Muralidharan

Comment: Part a) The first box can be filled in $\binom{40}{10}$ ways. The second in $\binom{30}{10}$ and so on and hence the total number of ways is $\binom{40}{10}\binom{30}{10}\binom{20}{10}\binom{10}{10} = \frac{40!}{30!10!}\frac{30}{20!10!}\frac{20!}{10!10!}\frac{10!}{10!0!} = \frac{40!}{(10!)^4}$. For part b), we need to count how many ways we can "label" four identical boxes - this is 24. Hence when the boxes are indistinguishable, each distribution is counted 24 times. Hence we need to divide by 24.

Comment: Is my assumption wrong..??isn't it the case of "distributing indistinguishable object into distinguishable box" ?? if so then can't we use the formula that i used ..?? @Muralidharan

Comment: If the 40 issues are indistinguishable, then we have only one way of putting them into 4 boxes 10 issues in each. If you remove the restriction that each box to contain 10, then your answer is correct.

Comment: got it ...my formula will work for repition but here it is not the case..!!